# dimension of subvariety of matrix of rank lesser or equal to $r$

Tags: linear-algebra, algebraic-geometry, differential-geometry, ideals

Let $M=Mat_{n\times n}(\mathbb{C})$. We know that Grassmanian $Gr_m(\mathbb{C}^n)$ is smooth and we can just need to find the dimension of a neighborhood of a point . We can use the fact that it is a homogenous space to prove that it actually has the required dimension.

Now let $X_r$ be the subvariety of $M$ to be all matrices of rank lesser or equal to $r$.

At the beginning , I want to use the same techique to find the dimension of $X_r$ but later I realized $X_r$ may not be smooth. I can't define it as a homogenous space.

Does anyone can provide some hints for me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can see all this done by looking up (or Googling) "determinantal variety."  For instance, it's done on the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinantal_variety), and there's a more comprehensive section in Harris's *Algebraic Geometry: A First Course*.